# Adding Params to React-Query When Clicking a Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, react-query

How do I add params when clicking a button using `react-query`?
I don't want to load the api on page load, I instead want to load the api when clicking a button.

[Code sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-solomon-3dz3zy?file=/demo.js)

```js
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import api from "./api";

export const fetchSimulateAccessRights = ({ productCode, gid }, config) => {
  return api.get(
    `/simulate-access-rights?productCode=${productCode}&gid=${gid}`,
    config
  );
};

export const useFetchSimulateAccessRightsQuery = (data) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ["simulate-access-rights", data],
    queryFn: () => fetchSimulateAccessRights(data),
    enabled: false
  });
};
```

demo.js

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useFetchSimulateAccessRightsQuery } from "./simulate-access-right.api";
import getCustomToolbar from "./CustomToolbar";

const CustomToolbar = getCustomToolbar();

const SimulateAccessRights = () => {
  const groupRef = useRef();
  const productRef = useRef();
  const { data, isLoading } = useFetchSimulateAccessRightsQuery({
    productCode: productRef?.current?.value || "",
    gid: groupRef?.current?.value || ""
  });

  const handleSimulateClick = () => {};

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CustomToolbar
        handleSimulateClick={handleSimulateClick}
        groupRef={groupRef}
        productRef={productRef}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default SimulateAccessRights;
```

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I wouldn't make the hook conditional on pressing a button, I would make the component that uses the hook conditional on pressing a button.

Comment: @ChadS. Can you fork my codesandbox?

Comment: In your code sandbox you could create a new component `SimulationRights` that would take `data` as a prop, and would use the hook you have here. Then you conditionally render that component when the user presses the button.

Comment: I've demonstrated what I mean here: https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-meadow-6yowz5?file=/demo.js

Comment: @ChadS. Can you check your network tab? It seems its not calling the API.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the `enabled: false` from the options in your `useQuery` call. You don't want/need that with this construction..

Comment: Just removed it. The api is being called now. The problem remaining is that `productCode` and `gid` is always undefined. Also, the data to be displayed is different from what should be pass the the query params.

Comment: Entirely possible, but that's not really relevant to this conversation. As you can see I've demonstrated how to solve the problem by conditionally rendering the the query component rather than conditionally running the query. This is the correct way to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell you can disable the query from running automatically and then manually invoke a returned `refetch` function.

See [useQuery](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/reference/useQuery) docs.

> `refetch: (options: { throwOnError: boolean, cancelRefetch: boolean }) => Promise<UseQueryResult>`
>
> - A function to manually refetch the query.
> - If the query errors, the error will only be logged. If you want an error to be thrown, pass the `throwOnError: true` option
> - `cancelRefetch?: boolean`
>
>   - Defaults to `true`
>
>     - Per default, a currently running request will be cancelled before a new request is made
>   - When set to `false`, no refetch will
>     be made if there is already a request running.

One issue you'll need to fix though is the data passed to the query. Using the React refs doesn't trigger a component rerender so that the `useFetchSimulateAccessRightsQuery` hook, and by extension the `useQuery` hook, isn't called again to close over the group id and product code values from the inputs/textfields. Convert these to React states and pass a callback to the toolbar component to update this state.

Example:

```
const SimulateAccessRights = () => {
  const [gid, setGid] = useState("");
  const [productCode, setProductCode] = useState("");

  const {
    data,
    isLoading,
    refetch // <-- access refetch function
  } = useFetchSimulateAccessRightsQuery({
    productCode,
    gid
  });

  const handleSimulateClick = () => {
    refetch(); // <-- manually invoke in click handler
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CustomToolbar
        saveHandler={handleSimulateClick}
        groupOnChange={setGid}
        productOnChange={setProductCode}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

```
export default function getCustomToolbar() {
  function CustomToolbar({
    saveHandler = () => {},
    groupOnChange = () => {},
    productOnChange = () => {}
  }) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Stack direction="row" gap={3} sx={{ ml: 0.5 }}>
          <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" gap={1}>
            <Typography variant="h6">User group:</Typography>
            <TextField
              size="small"
              placeholder="Enter user group"
              onChange={(e) => groupOnChange(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Stack>
          <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" gap={1}>
            <Typography variant="h6">Product:</Typography>
            <TextField
              size="small"
              placeholder="Enter product"
              onChange={(e) => productOnChange(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Stack>
        </Stack>
        <Button variant="contained" onClick={saveHandler}>
          Save
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return CustomToolbar;
}
```

[image: Edit adding-params-to-react-query-when-clicking-a-button]

I hit a CORS error in your attached codesandbox with the above code changes, but all indications show the UI at least made the query network request when the "SAVE" button was clicked, which it seems is the behavior you describe wanting.

Comment: You're answering a question he's not really asking because he doesn't really understand what he wants to do. The correct thing to do in this case is not to somehow conditionally call the hook or trigger the query, but rather to conditionally render the component which will use the query.

Comment: @ChadS. I think it's clear OP asks to "run the query" in response to "clicking a button". Not wanting to immediately run a query when a component mounts because there's a dependency on some user input is a legitimate use case, generally speaking. I do this all the time using `redux-toolkit/query`, just needed to read up on a method to accomplish the same or similar with this other library. This answer is just *a way* to accomplish the goal.

Comment: @Joseph The issue in your last comment appears to be unrelated to this post regarding working with the query hook. It would be better as a new post and topic on its own.

Comment: @Joseph Ah, ok, got it running after some more aggressive cache clearing. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: @Joseph This seems to be an issue with the grid component you are using. Passing the `gid` and `productCode` state to`Toolbar` sort of fixes the issue but the grid component is recreating a new tool bar instance each time the component renders, so typing into the input's loses focus upon each update.

Comment: @Joseph Dunno, your questions and sandboxes have been the only time I've ever interacted with that library and to be quite honest, it's a pain to work with.

Comment: @DrewReese and I'm saying that this is counter to the library use-case. It's like suggesting some overly complicated messaging system to solve the problem of sibling components needing access to the same state. Yes you could do that, but the right answer is to lift the state. Yes you can make the query not run until some user action, but the right solution is to not render the component that uses the query until some user interaction.